# View with gradient is staying white after setting LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I want a stylish gradient look for my app. Therefore I tried to also color the navigation bar with a gradient. I'm getting the height of the bar first and then change the layout params. The color is after resizing white. Has anyone of you an idea why it stays white?

Here you can see how it looks like now

[image: Screenshot of current layout]

### Code

```
ImageView navBarBackground =
findViewById(R.id.navigationbar_background);
         Resources resources = this.getResources();
         int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
         if (resourceId > 0) {
             navBarBackground.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(navBarBackground.getWidth(),
 resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)));
             navBarBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.gradient_orange);
             navBarBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
```

I also tried to do it by changing the background. It didnt work out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_sammlung"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activities.SammlungActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/sammlung_toolbar"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_orange"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view_gegenstaende"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <de.lucadmin.sammelapp.dslv.DragSortListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_gegenstaende"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        app:drag_start_mode="onLongPress"
        android:visibility="visible">

    </de.lucadmin.sammelapp.dslv.DragSortListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gegenstand_button_hinzufuegen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hinzufügen"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gegenstand_button_einstellungen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_art_track_black_24dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Layout ändern"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigationbar_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### How it's supposed to look:

[image: Screenshot of expected layout]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** you have to use `MATCH_PARENT` for the `ImageView` width:

```
navBarBackground.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)));
```

By using `navBarBackground.getWidth()` you set the width of the `ImageButton` to zero, so all you see is the window background.

This happens because the `ImageView` is not yet completely laid out when you evaluate the width in `onCreate()`. (see also for example this blog post on [The Life Cycle of a View in Android](https://proandroiddev.com/the-life-cycle-of-a-view-in-android-6a2c4665b95e))

Useful tool for debugging layouts: [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)

Comment: The problem is the ImageView(android:id="@+id/navigationbar_background") beneath the two buttons. Its behind the navigation bar and should also have a orange color gradient. But it is white

Comment: @Lucadmin - With the layout you posted, it is not behind the navigation bar but below it (shows up between buttons and bottom of screen). I can't tell why it's white because you did not provide enough code to reproduce the situation. The problem with posting only snippets is that I might accidentally fix your code. Then I can't find out what's wrong and so I can't really help you.

Comment: If I set an fixed height of the view its working. Give me two minutes and I send you how it is supposed to look. Sorry I havent provided it yet

Comment: Change it. When I change it to a fixed height, its looking like I want it to look

Comment: @Lucadmin - OK. Good to see that screenshot, now I finally understand the problem. I'll get back to you if I find out how to solve it